# onClick not working inside the pop up opened via React portals

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the code that I have implemented:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {Link} from 'react-router'
import {Table, Column} from '../../Layout/components/Table'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
// import ExternalPortal from '../../Sites/components/ExternalPortal'

export const TableName = 'ProjectDashboard'

class MyWindowPortal extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
    closeWindowPortal: PropTypes.func
  }

  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.containerEl = document.createElement('div') // STEP 1: create an empty div
    this.externalWindow = null
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // STEP 3: open a new browser window and store a reference to it
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400')

    // STEP 4: append the container <div> (that has props.children appended to it) to the body of the new window
    this.externalWindow.document.body.appendChild(this.containerEl)

    this.externalWindow.document.title = 'A React portal window'
    // copyStyles(document, this.externalWindow.document)

    // update the state in the parent component if the user closes the
    // new window
    this.externalWindow.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      this.props.closeWindowPortal()
    })
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    // This will fire when this.state.showWindowPortal in the parent component becomes false
    // So we tidy up by just closing the window
    this.externalWindow.close()
  }

  render () {
    // STEP 2: append props.children to the container <div> that isn't mounted anywhere yet
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl)
  }
}


export default class ProjectTable extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state={showWindowPortal:false}

    this.toggleWindowPortal = this.toggleWindowPortal.bind(this)
    this.closeWindowPortal = this.closeWindowPortal.bind(this)
  }

  static propTypes = {
    data: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    loginId: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', () => {
      this.closeWindowPortal()
    })
  }

  toggleWindowPortal () {
    this.setState({showWindowPortal: !this.state.showWindowPortal})
  }

  closeWindowPortal () {
    this.setState({showWindowPortal: false})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>

        <div>
          <p>This div is just for testing click here to see the portal</p>
          {
            this.state.showWindowPortal &&
            (
              <MyWindowPortal closeWindowPortal={this.closeWindowPortal}>
                <button
                  onClick={() => this.closeWindowPortal()}
                >
                  Close
                </button>
              </MyWindowPortal>
            )
          }

          <button onClick={this.toggleWindowPortal}>
            {this.state.showWindowPortal ? 'Close the' : 'Open a'} Portal
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The button inside the portal doesn't trigger anything on click. It doesn't fire at all. Please note that MyWindowPortal opens a new window and the button gets rendered in that window. Tried testing it on Firefox and Chrome. I am not sure if I am doing anything wrong.

Comment: You're opening in a new windows literally? Not just a div? An old school popup? If not check nothing is invisibly obscuring the button and that the callback is definitely not being called.

Comment: @DominicTobias Yes, I am opening a new window and not just in the div. Yea, like an old-school pop up. The obscure thing came to my mind too. Trying to figure out how to find what's obscuring? Or maybe that's not an issue at all. Followed https://hackernoon.com/using-a-react-16-portal-to-do-something-cool-2a2d627b0202

Comment: Sounds complex, you need to treat a new window just like a new web page that needs to load in react and your code and attach to a node etc

Comment: I have the same problem as well. Any solutions ?

Answer (score 4):

The solution has been posted here
https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/12355

The issue is that you're first creating a DOM node in one document, but then moving it to another one. However React has already bound the event handlers to the first document. React doesn't expect that you would move a DOM node between documents while something is rendered into it

To fix it, you can change your code so that you move the node before rendering something into in React

```
class Window extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { win: null, el: null };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let win = window.open('', '', 'width=600,height=400');
    win.document.title = 'A React portal window';
    let el = document.createElement('div');
    win.document.body.appendChild(el);
    this.setState({ win, el });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.state.win.close();
  }

  render() {
    const { el } = this.state;
    if (!el) {
      return null;
    }
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, el);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faiced the same problems with onClick handlers but in my case I used component inside WindowPortal.
My workaround for the problem was usage of ref's and manual assignment of onclick event handlers to each of button elements I had inside my component.
Here is snippet example:

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.ref = (element) => {
      element.querySelector('button.one').onclick = () => {
        alert( 'One!' );
      }
      element.querySelector('button.two').onclick = () => {
        alert( 'Two!' );
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="some-component" ref={this.ref}>
      <button type='button' className='one'>Click One</button>
      <button type='button' className='two'>Click Two</button>
    </div>;
  }
}
```

Btw, I'm using redux and SomeComponent successfully connects to store and allows dispatching of actions.